# Webservice : AsyncCall finished : But WaitOne() still waiting

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynccallback, manualresetevent, waitone

1. I am calling  a WebService method via a Command Line Exe.
2. This method call is Async Call and I am using WaitOne after the Call.
3. I am doing ManualRest.Set() in completed method.

The above setup works fine 99% of the cases where the async method returns withing 10-20 mintues,

**Problem occurs**
when the Async Call takes more time like 2-3 hours then the code after WaitOne() is not being executed.

I am writing logs before and after waitone() and in Completed event also but the control does not seems back after a 3 hours of async call.

Any help / pointer on above ...

Thanks.

Comment: Please post some code instead of just describing it. The details are important, and they get lost when you describe your code in your own words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that Set is being called? Are you using `System.Diagnostics.Process`? Please post the code for how you use the process in your question.

When using a process there is an extremely high risk of creating a deadlock, especially if you use the code examples on MSDN that show you how to read from StandardIn and StandardOut synchronously.

Try using the asynchronous read methods instead to avoid deadlock.

- [`Process.BeginOutputReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx)
- [`Process.BeginErrorReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginerrorreadline.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Yes i am using System.Diagnostics.Process and so far not using BeginOutputReadLine , will try out...